# How to visualize / debug SQLite database? (python application)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

What would be the best tool to debug / visualize & dig in to the a SQLite database in application development phase. The tool should be free or cheap (max. 50 USD).

#### What kind of development environment I have?

- I am creating the app & databases using python. Tools I am using include [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) and  [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)
- I am working on a Windows machine, but tools for other platforms are also welcomed.

#### What other tools there are?

- For Postgres, there comes [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) which shows Columns, Indexes, and basically anything that the database has. It has nice graphical (browser) interface for that. Something similar to this would be optimal.
- For SQLite in Android devices there are few options, like [DatabaseManager_For_Android](https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android) or [Android-Debug-Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) but they seem to be tighty coupled with Android development environments and Java.
- What is the closest I have came up to is [Flask-Admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but I would be interested to see if there is any more general tools for SQLite that are not tied to Flask applications only, and which could perhaps give even more detailed look into the database (like pgAdmin).

Comment: Did you get an answer? It is quite trivial to open the database and parse the schema, but I don't know how to display it visually :-(

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: What was the coding problem? Accessing the database, or visualizing it?

Comment: Wait maybe I misunderstand. Do you want us to recommend an app to explore your database, or do you want to code iit yourself?

Comment: Well I was searhing for any kind of tool that could be used to visualize SQLite databases. The more generic the tool the better. It could be some python package requiring a bit of coding but it also could be an app. Something like the pgAdmin for Postgres, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sqlite workbench](https://www.sqlite-workbench.com/)

> SQLite Workbench is a full SQLite editor which allows you to create, edit and manage your SQLite databases. It also allows you to export data or access it through remote REST API call, giving you a full database cloud based on SQLite.

> No more need to use desktop software to modify tables, add/edit/remove data or setup database preferences.

> SQLite Workbench allows you to directly run queries using TSQL, saving your preferences (like cache, journal mode, etc...), use foreign keys and managing them via simple diagrams and also connect your app using simple REST API.

For the visualization part:

> Main problem most users find using SQLite is often there is no actual GUI to managing tables nor foreign keys.

> SQLite Workbench is thinked and designed to easy handle diagrams. It is now possible to create diagrams using existing tables, create new tables directly inside diagrams editor, add or remove foreign keys even defining ON DELETE and ON UPDATE actions.

> Diagrams can also be saved without being executed, allowing to change settings anytime.

[image]

Is this the sort of thing that you are looking for?